# How to use OR function in a statement

Tags: php

I want to set `$a = 5` between 09.00h and 16.59h, Monday to Friday.

```
   $time = time()%86400;
   if( (date("D") == "Mon") || (date("D") == "Tue") || (date("D") == "Wed") || 
   (date("D") == "Thu") || (date("D") == "Fri") && $time >= 32400 && $time <= 61119){
        $a = 5;
    }
```

Have does the && time read at the end? Does it read "Mon OR Tue OR Wed OR Thu OR Fri..." AND "Time...", or instead "Fri AND Time"?

Comment: Throw a set of parenthesis around the date checks. That should separate it, so it's date statements and time. You could also check if it's not Saturday or Sunday to cut down on logic. Right now, it's Friday and time.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you'll need a set of parenthesis around the ORs, but a slightly cleaner way to write this might be:

```
if( in_array((date("D"), array("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"))
     && $time >= 32400 && $time <= 61119 ){
```

or even:

`!in_array((date("D"), array("Sat","Sun"))`